# JSP throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, jsp

I keep getting a Null Pointer Exception, and I can't tell from the stack trace exactly what is causing it. It seems to point to line 83 in DisplayAccounts.jsp but the file is only 48 lines long...
After logging in, the LoginServlet is supposed to direct user to DisplayAccounts.jsp

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to figure it out.

DisplayAccounts.jsp:

```
    <h1>Customer Accounts</h1>                
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Account Type</th>
            <th>Account Balance</th>
        </tr>
    <% ArrayList accounts = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("customer.list");
    for(int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
        Account account = (Account)accounts.get(i); %>
        <tr>
            <td><% out.print(account.getAcctNo());%></td>
            <td><% out.print(account.getcID());%></td>
            <td><% out.print(account.getType());%></td>
            <td><% out.print(account.getBalance());%></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
```

LoginServlet.java :

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String id;
        String pw;
        int idDB;
        String pwDB;
        HttpSession session;
        try{
            id = request.getParameter("custID");
            pw = request.getParameter("pswd");
            System.out.println("ID: " + id);
            System.out.println("Password: " + pw);
            idDB = Integer.parseInt(id);

            Customer c1 = new Customer();
            c1.selectDB(idDB);
            pwDB = c1.getCustPassword();                
            // Add user to session
            session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("customer", c1);
            System.out.println("User added to session");
            if (pw.equals(pwDB)){
                // Send user to account look up page
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("DisplayAccount.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }

            else{
                // Send user to error page
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("ErrorPage.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
        }
        catch(ServletException e){
            System.out.println("A Servlet Excpetion has occured");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("An IO Exception has occured");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("An error has occurred.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Exception Stack Trace:

```
Info:   A Servlet Excpetion has occured
Info:   java.lang.NullPointerException
Info:   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.DisplayAccount_jsp._jspService(DisplayAccount_jsp.java:83)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at Chatt_Bank.LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:45)
    at Chatt_Bank.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: No, it points to line 83 in `DisplayAccount_jsp.java` - a Java servlet compiled from your JSP.

Comment: You do `session.setAttribute("customer", c1);` in your servlet, but `session.getAttribute("customer.list")` in the JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
ArrayList accounts = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("customer.list");
```

`accounts` is null. You haven't set a `HttpSession` parameter with a name of `customer.list` using

```
HttpSession#setAttribute(String name, Object o)
```

([setAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))) inside your `LoginServlet#processRequest` method. So, when

```
if (pw.equals(pwDB)){
```

You're forwarding to `DisplayAccount.jsp` **without** that value.

---

You need to add

```
session.setAttribute("customer.list", customerList);
```

---

You cannot do what you want to do, you need another attribute

```
session.setAttribute("customerList", c1.list); // or c1.getList() if you have a getter
```

Comment: I see! This makes sense and I understand where I went wrong. Thank you for pointing this out! I do have a follow-up question. The reason I put "customer.list" is because list is a property of my customer object (my mind assumed it would work this way, I forgot how literal strings work oops). I'm supposed to be sending the customer object, and then iterating through this list of objects stored in the customer's list attribute. How do I go about accessing these objects in the list, via the customer object? I know this can be confusing, let me know how I can clarify in any way

Comment: Thanks! Such simple fixes. I feel silly for getting so confused. Thank you!

Comment: @kotlinkitty no problem. It happens to everyone sometimes.